# C# DateTime: Scaling Double to Time

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a function that returns a step size from a bounded range.  So if the range is {1,2,3,4,5,6..10} and I want 5 steps it would return a step size of 2.  This isn't that complicated.

If I have {.1,.2,.3,.4....1} and I want 7 steps the step size is 0.14285.  I then want to convert 0.14285 to the nearest relevant time measurement.  In this case .14285 represents a fractional day.  For example, the integer 1 would represent a whole day and .25 would represent 6 hours.

```
.14285 = 12,342.24 seconds = 205.704 Minutes = 3.42 Hours ~= 4 hours.
```

I then want to snap .14285 to (4*60*60 = 14,400 / (24*60*60)) = .16666 which is the decimal equivalent of 4 hours.

I more or less have the math figured out, but I'm wondering if there is an easier way of doing this using DateTime stuff?

Comment: question: why is 0.14285 equal to 4 hours?  I don't get that.

Comment: if the integer 1 is equal to a single day, .25 is equal to 6 hours.  .14285 is then equal to 3.42 hours.  I then rounded up to 4 hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do recommend that you make your question clearer; it took me a while to realize that the `0.14285` you were referring to represented a fraction of a *day*.

You can use something like this:

```
 // {03:25:42.24}
TimeSpan unSnapped = TimeSpan.FromDays(0.14285);

 // {04:00:00} : Round up the hours and construct a TimeSpan from it
TimeSpan snapped = TimeSpan.FromHours(Math.Ceiling(unSnapped.TotalHours));

// 0.166666666
double snappedFractionOfADay = snapped.TotalDays;
```

You can inspect the `TotalXXX` properties on the time-spans to get the other information you mention, if needed.

Comment: This worked wonderfully.  I was hopping for something like this and you delivered.  THANKS!