# How to convert double value to a time? C#/ASP.NET

Tags: c#

How can I convert `double` value to time?
for example I have this `double` value 
`val = 0.00295692867015203` and I want to return `4:15`.

I have done a lot of research and did not find a solution that worked!  Here is a function that I have tried also but it returns `00:00:00`:

`ConvertFromDecimalToDDHHMM(Convert.ToDecimal(val));`

```
public string ConvertFromDecimalToDDHHMM(decimal dHours) {
    try {
        decimal hours = Math.Floor(dHours); //take integral part
        decimal minutes = (dHours - hours) * 60.0M; //multiply fractional part with 60
        int D = (int)Math.Floor(dHours / 24);
        int H = (int)Math.Floor(hours - (D * 24));
        int M = (int)Math.Floor(minutes);
        //int S = (int)Math.Floor(seconds);   //add if you want seconds
        string timeFormat = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", D, H, M);

        return timeFormat;
    }
    catch (Exception) {
        throw;
    }
}
```

I am using `C#` and `ASP.NET`.  I will appreciate any advise.

Comment: How do you get 4:15 from 0.00295692867015203? I mean, what is that double value?

Comment: How exactly does `0.00295692867015203` turn into `4:15`? Is that AM? PM?

Comment: Its the number of days. 0.00295692867015203 * 24 * 60 = 4.2579772850189232. 0.2579772850189232 * 60 = 15; so 4:15

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211218/c-sharp-datetime-scaling-double-to-time. SUGGESTION: Please make your question clear (whether the input is days etc..) so everyone could help you better. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 14):

Wow...took me a while to realize you meant `"00:04:15.00"`....

`public static TimeSpan TimeSpan.FromDays(double value)` will get you a `TimeSpan`

And `DateTime.Today.AddDays(double value)` will get you a date time

Answer (score 7):

I think you want something like `TimeSpan.FromDays(0.00295692867015203)`. The `TimeSpan` function takes a `double` value and returns `TimeSpan` object (naturally): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromdays.aspx.

This `TimeSpan` object can then be used in date-time arithmetic, like the following:

```
var now = DateTime.Now; // say, 25/13/2013 12:23:34
var interval = TimeSpan.FromDays(0.00295692867015203); // 4:15
var futureTime = now + interval; // 25/13/2013 12:27:49
```

Comment: Eeek, StackOverflow can't deal with MSDN links these days. :/

Comment: Yeah, I had that happen just a second ago on another answer...what's up with that, SO?

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
public static string ConvertFromDoubleToDDHHMM(double days) {
  return TimeSpan.FromDays(days).ToString(@"dd\:hh\:mm");
}
```

It first creates a value of the `TimeSpan` struct and then formats that value as a `string`. See [Custom TimeSpan Format Strings on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx) for details.

Works for .NET 4.0 and later.